# Preformatted print AskUbuntu thread to printer or (even better) to PDF

Tags: feature-request

There are some web sites with embedded 'download as PDF' feature. In many occasions it would be very useful to have a PDF version of AskUbuntu thread. Therefore, I would like to suggest adding 'Print/Download as PDF' to AskUbuntu interface.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://www.stackprinter.com/ is a great tool for this.

Comment: Thanks Jorge !!! It's a very good "external" application for stack printing. What about integration of PDF printer to AskUbuntu (and other stacks) interface ? :)

Comment: There's a greasemonkey script there you can install, dunno about on the interface on AU itself, that'd be up to the SO developers.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes, it's up to the SO developers to make such changes.

Comment: Anyway, I (and many SO users :)) would be very grateful if somebody from SO developers could intergrate PDF printing (saving) for SO threads. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, stackprinter is a great tool, yet it doesn't work for all the sites and would be good to have it advanced for askubuntu and others or may be have another version of a tool to get printable versions.